# Warning: [-Wformat=] and strcmp() not comparing in C

Tags: c

I'm making a simple code in C programming. To Be Honest with you guys I have quite a while that I don't program in it. So I wanted to make a simple program to reintroduce myself to this programming language.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char email;
    char temppass[64];
    char pass[] = "password";

    printf("Enter your email: \n");
    scanf("%s", &email);

    printf("Enter your password: \n");
    scanf("%s" , &temppass);


    if(strcmp(temppass, pass) == 0){

        printf("This is the password");

    }


    else{

        printf("You Failed!");


    }

return 0;

}
```

Though I'm having some problems which I can't solve. The first problem is that it is giving me an warning:

`strcmp2.c: In function ‘main’:
strcmp2.c:14:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[64]’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s" , &temppass);
            ~^    ~~~~~~~~~`

I'm pretty aware that this question might look duplicate as other questions but as far as I have searched and read all questions and answers, none of them could help me since they were different and didn't helped me.

At first, I tried to solve it with `fgets()` as an input function. When compiling the code, it didn't gave me nor warnings or errors but the problem with it is that `fgets` puts a `\n` new line character at the end of input. So the user input and the string I'm comparing are not the same. I tried adding the new line character at `char pass[]="password\n"` to see if it solves anything, but it failed again.

Though, when I run it and inputs the requested info, the `strcmp()` function will not successfully compare the two strings, even if the password input is the same.

If anyone would help me, I really appreciate you and your precious time. Many Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: "fgets puts a \n new line character at the end of input." --> follow `fgets()` with  `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;` to lop off a potential ending `\n`.

Comment: thecow milk, As a re-introduction to C, consider never using `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your password test isn't working is related to the warning. When temppass is declared as an array, it is really a pointer to statically allocated memory. So when you take the address of it, you are no longer pointing to the beginning of the array you are pointing to a variable who's value points to the beginning of the array. The situation is similar to this code:

```c
char *c = malloc(42);
scanf("%s", &c);
```

As you can see, we are giving `scanf` a `char **` not a `char *`.

As others have noted, the `email` variable should probably be an array as well, and the call to `scanf` should not take the address of email at that point either.

Additionally, it is best to explicitly initialize your variables and bound your input. For the former, if you are compiling without optimizations then the compiler is probably zeroing out your memory already, but when you get into production code uninitialized variables are dangerous. Similarly, since the input is being placed into statically allocated arrays scanf should be told to limit the number of characters it copies.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char email[64] = { 0 };
    char temppass[64] = { 0 };
    char pass[] = "password";

    printf("Enter your email: \n");
    int scanf_return_value = scanf("%63s", email);
    if (scanf_return_value != 1) {
        printf("Error parsing input!\n");
        if (scanf_return_value == EOF) {
            perror("scanf");
        } else {
            printf("scanf returned unexpected value %d", scanf_return_value);
        }
    }

    printf("Enter your password: \n");
    scanf_return_value = scanf("%63s" , temppass);
    if (scanf_return_value != 1) {
        printf("Error parsing input!\n");
        if (scanf_return_value == EOF) {
            perror("scanf");
        } else {
            printf("scanf returned unexpected value %d", scanf_return_value);
        }
    }

    if(strcmp(temppass, pass) == 0) {
        printf("This is the password");
    }
    else {
        printf("You Failed!");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unlike with `fgets` the length restriction for `scanf` excludes the string terminator, so here it should be `%63s` and also, it is also important to check the return value from scanf function family, which in your example must be `1`.

Comment: @saffronsnail , thanks for your answer and for your lecture. As I said it in the beginning, I have so much time that I program in other programming languages and I was starting to forget C. I have edited the code and it working well now :D :)

Comment: "best to explicitly initialize your variables and bound your input." is reasonable advice, but then this code does `scanf("%64s", email);` without checking the return value - a greater problem.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks for pointing out those issues, they have been fixed now. However, the return value of scanf will not be 1 unless the user only enters 1 character of input.

Comment: @chux Thanks for pointing out my omission, but I do not agree that not checking the return value of scanf is a greater error. Not bounding the input could allow the user to execute arbitrary code in the context of the program, while not checking the return value will cause the program to fail silently but not damage the integrity of the system.

Comment: @saffronsnail Fair enough - it was the first part "initialize your variables" that I was comparing to lack of return checking.   Yes, limiting input to 63 is the  bigger problem,

Comment: @saffronsnail `scanf` functions return *the number of items successfully scanned.* So one format specifier `%s` returns `1` item scanned (if successful). It has no bearing on the *value* that was scanned.

Comment: @Weather Vane Correct you are! I still think the code above which compares against EOF is fine, since EOF is returned in an error condition. Do you agree?

Comment: @saffronsnail No, I don't. This is far better than testing for `EOF`. Suppose you asked for two `int` values and the user enters `42 A` the return value of `scanf` will be `1` not `EOF`, and it must be `2`. If usee enters `A 42` the return value will be `0` not `EOF`.

Comment: @WeatherVane But in this particular case we are scanning a single string; there is no partial failure case. If the code is updated to take 2 values then I agree it would need to look like that, but the error checking would need to be updated no matter which strategy we use for the current form.

Comment: Still, the proper way is to check the number of items returned. if it is not what was expected you can *then* check for `EOF`. Otherwise you learn nothing about the input. There is no reason to treat a string input any different.

Comment: I'm not treating it differently because it's a string, I'm treating it differently because there's only 1 expected input. So the function will either return 1 or EOF.

Comment: Good, suppose you are entering *two* strings. If you always check the number of items entered then you don't have to make any value judgements about which is better, or use a different procedure in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

`email` can only store one character, not a string. And you don't need the `&` in the scanf when you give the address of the array (`temppass` is  `&temppass[0]`).

try this instead:

```
char email[64];
char temppass[64];
char *pass = "password";

printf("Enter your email: \n");
scanf("%s", email);

printf("Enter your password: \n");
scanf("%s" , temppass);
```

Beware that the way you read your string is not safe if the length of the input is greater than the length of the string.

Comment: NMDV, but `scanf("%s", email);` is like `gets()` (which is bad) which both have no buffer limit.  `char email[64]; scanf("%63s", email);` is better.

Comment: `scanf("%s" , temppass);` does not allow space in a password.  Consider ditching all `scanf()` and use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

`email` variable is a single character, and you are trying to pass a string into it.

Make it `email[50];` and remove the `&` in `scanf` when you're reading a string from `stdin`, this is what triggers the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because the type of `&temppass` is, as it says, pointer-to-array-of-char; with `scanf`, the `"%s"` specifier expects a pointer-to-char. Easy to fix. Change

```
scanf("%s" , &temppass);
```

to

```
scanf("%s" , temppass);
```

that is, remove the `&`.